# Firebase Dynamic Links auto navigation

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Dealing with a weird situation. Removed/commented out all code related to Dynamic Links but deep linking still works. If the link's path matches AutoRoute's path, then can it be picked automatically and navigated? Any idea why Firebase Dynamic links are still working even though all initialization code is removed?